# Sharepoint 2010 databases - How to move to standalone SQL 2012 from SQL 2012 AlwaysOn

Tags: database, sharepoint, alias, sql-server-2012, high-availability

We recently purchased a well known backup solution and even after assurances that it could backup SQL 2012 databases and that our SQL 2012 AlwaysOn HA solution would not be a problem, it transpires they actually don't support it at the moment.

So my only option, it seems, is to ditch the AlwaysOn facility until such time as they do support it (for reference, this company do not offer refunds on their software!!).

I should mention that the SharePoint 2010 environment we have is a live production environment, not a test one.

My question is, my SharePoint 2010 installation is currently referencing the SQL2012 AlwaysOn Listener to connect to the database (in this case, SP-SQL-AG1CA).  I've read about the way to transfer SharePoint databases from one SQL server to another, but nothing about if you want to just reference a server that hosts the existing SQL databases rather than referencing the AlwaysOn listeners.  If possible, I'd rather not have to set up a new SQL server to move the databases across as they are perfectly fine where they are!

Is it possible to effectively tear down an AlwaysOn setup, and just use a SQL Alias with the same name (e.g. SP-SQL-AG1CA) on the standalone SQL server after changing the Active Directory DNS entry to point to the now standalone SQL Server (i.e. in DNS NH-SQLSVR-01 = 10.1.10.150 so change SP-SQL-AG1CA to also point to 10.1.10.150)?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that will work fine, we use DNS cnames to migrate servers reasonably often.

What I would do is:

- Remove the databases from the availability group
- Delete the listener
- Create a DNS cname with the same name as the old listener pointing towards the server that hosts your databases
- Do an ipconfig /flushdns command on the share point servers to make sure they notice the IP address change